# Prioritizing array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are 3 empty arrays (a, b, c) and another array (d) with some dynamic values. I need to pass the array values to 'a','b' and 'c' arrays as in the below pattern;

Rather than having seperate IF statements is there a way to write it simpler?

```
const arrayA = [];
const arrayB = [];
const arrayC = [];
const arrays = [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC];
const arrayD = ['some', 'values', 'here'];

if(arrayD.length <= 3) {
   for(i=0; i<3; i++){
       arrayA.push(arrays[i][i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You will need something like modulo `1%3 !=0` but not sure what will be the algo for this.

Comment: @Patfreeze Nice!! Thanks :)

Comment: @Fergoso what if you have 7 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simplified if we can calculate the lengths of the output arrays. These are shown in the snippet as `al` and `bl`. The third length will be the remainder after slicing away the first two.  With that...

```js
const input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
let length = input.length;

let al = Math.ceil(length / 3);
let bl = Math.ceil((length - al )/ 2);

let a = input.slice(0, al);
let b = input.slice(al, al+bl);
let c = input.slice(al+bl);

console.log([a, b, c])
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT! in my first version I misunderstood the question

This is one way to do it, if I understood your question correctly

```js
const arrayA = [];
const arrayB = [];
const arrayC = [];
const arrays = [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC];
const arrayD = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function myArray(arr) {
  let temp = [
    [],
    [],
    []
  ]
  if (arrayD.length <= 3) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayD.length; i = i + 3) {
      temp[0].push(arrayD[i]);
      arrayD[i + 1] === undefined ? null : temp.push(arrayD[i + 1])
      arrayD[i + 2] === undefined ? null : temp.push(arrayD[i + 2])
      arrayA.push(temp[0])
    }
  } else {
    let index = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayD.length; i = i + 3) {
      arrayD[i] === undefined ? null :
        temp[index].push(arrayD[i])
      arrayD[i + 1] === undefined ? null : temp[index].push(arrayD[i + 1]);
      arrayD[i + 2] === undefined ? null : temp[index].push(arrayD[i + 2])

      index++

    }
    arrayA.push(...temp[0])
    arrayB.push(...temp[1])
    arrayC.push(...temp[2])

  }
  arrays.push[arrayA, arrayB, arrayC]

}

myArray(arrayD)
console.log(arrays)
```

Comment: Thanks J_K. So in your 8 value example, Array 'a' shows 1,4,7.  I'm expecting 1,2,3.

Comment: oh, my mistake, I thought you need every 4th value to be pushed to the 1st array.

Comment: :) you can refer the 8 value example in the question. cheers!

Comment: @Fergoso I edited my snippet to output the desired result